# how to sort array with number in behind number?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which is sorted with front number (20(news....). I am having trouble sorting with next number in behind.  If I use `strval`, in number 10,20,30..and number with one digit like 1,2,3...certain any problem:

```
Array
( 
    [20(news)19:17] => Array
        (
            [Edisi] => 192Oktober2001 
        )
    [20(news)10:17] => Array
        (
            [Edisi] => 192Oktober2001 
        )
 )
```

I mean

```
[20(news)10:17] => Array
        (
            [Edisi] => 192Oktober2001 
        )
[20(news)19:17] => Array
        (
            [Edisi] => 192Oktober2001 
        )
```

Comment: @Lion I've attempted to clarify the wording a bit as well.

Comment: couldn't you make a better array in the first place? what generates this?

Comment: @ jadarnel27:) I have approved your edit. Wait for other vote.

Comment: @JoeMerra don't comment your own question, edit the original

Answer (score 1):

Simple [`ksort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) does the trick, if you are sure "`(news)`" part stays the same.

`ksort()` sorts the array based on the key and changes array in-place like that:

```
$array = array(
    '20(news)19:17' => array(
        'Edisi' => '192Oktober2001',
    ),
    '20(news)10:17' => array(
        'Edisi' => '192Oktober2001',
    ),
);

ksort($array);

// $array is sorted here
```

Proof: http://ideone.com/55nVN